# Weird output from Haskell until function

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a bit of code to help me with some math stuff. I'm trying to implement the Miller test, not Miller-Rabin, and I need to make a list of a bunch of exponents. Here's the code so far. It inserts the last result twice for some reason, and I don't know why. I must not understand how the until function works.

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Powers

divides::Integer->Integer->Bool
divides x y = y `mod` x == 0

factorcarmichael::Integer->(Integer,Integer)
factorcarmichael n = until (\(_, s) -> not $ divides 2 s)
                           (\(r, s) -> (r+1, div s 2))
                           (0, n-1)

second::((Integer,Integer),[Integer])->[Integer]
second (x,xs) = xs

millerlist::Integer->Integer->[Integer]
millerlist a n =  second $ until (\((r,s), xs) -> r<0)
                                 (\((r,s), xs) -> ((r-1,s), (powerMod a ((2^r)*s) n):xs))
                                 (factoredcarmichael, [])
    where 
        factoredcarmichael = factorcarmichael n
```

Also, the millerlist function is a little kludgy. If someone can suggest an alternative, that would be nice.

The output I'm getting for

```
millerlist 8888 9746347772161
```

repeats the last element twice.

Comment: I expanded my answer with alternative implementations, one of them may find your approval, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because

```
7974284540860^2 ≡ 7974284540860 (mod 9746347772161)
```

so the number appears twice in the list. But your list is one too long, I believe. I think you only want the remainder of `a^(2^k*s)` modulo `n` for `0 <= k < r`.

As for alternatives, is there a particular reason why you're not using `Math.NumberTheory.Primes.isStrongFermatPP`? If you're only interested in the outcome, that's less work coding.

If you want to generate the list, what about

```
millerlist a n = go r u
  where
    (r,s) = factorcarmichael n
    u = powerMod a s n
    go 0 m = []
    go k m = m : go (k-1) ((m*m) `mod` n)
```

or

```
millerlist a n = take (fromInteger r) $ iterate (\m -> (m*m) `mod` n) u
  where
    (r,s) = factorcarmichael n
    u = powerMod a s n
```

Comment: Yep there is. I need to see the base to each power p mod n such that 0<=p<r when n-1 is factored as 2^rs

Comment: Out of curiosity, what for? If by Miller test you mean what I think the Miller test is, all you need for that is checking the strong Fermat property for sufficiently many bases. Are you doing something else with the powers?

Comment: My math professor was mean and for spring break assigned performing the Miller test on a bunch of large numbers by hand (presumably. There was no specific "no computers" clause). I procrastinated, so I had to write a program to do the assignment for me. There aren't enough hours left in the day for me to finish this on time, by hand. I've tried to avoid asking any mathematics questions not directly related to the implementation because of this. The bases are asked for on the assignment.

Comment: For the record, I don't actually think it was a mean assignment. Just time consuming to do without a computer...